# Populate DropDownList from model/database in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been searching around for almost 3 days to find a solution to the following problem.
I'm simply trying to add a `DropDownList` in `RegisterViewModel (Identity)`.
During user registration I need to prompt for the `Gender`.

I have already inserted the following items in the table.

```
Code = F
Definition = Female
-------------------
Code = M
Definition = Male
```

When I generate the DropDownList directly inside GenderDDController and it's view it works perfectly but as soon as I'm in `RegisterViewModel` I have zero chance due to I can't reference multiple models in `Register.cshtml (View)`.

I should also indicate that I'm new to MVC and I'm sure that's the only reason that I look confused right now.

### GenderDD | Model

```
public partial class GenderDD
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Definition { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

### RegisterViewModel | Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
   ViewData["GenderList"] =
   Enum.GetValues(typeof (GenderDD))
     .Cast<GenderDD>()
     .Select(c => new SelectListItem {Text = c.ToString(), Value = c.ToString()});

   return View();
}
```

Comment: Show your `RegisterViewModel`

Comment: You need to add and populate a `SelectList` property in `RegisterViewModel`, then you can use it in the View

Comment: Edit your question with the code (not in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple classes in your model for `Register.cshtml (View)`

Simply create a base class such as below and reference it as the Model for that view, this will then give you access to two models.

```
Public Class RegisterViewModel()
{
    public ModelName ModelName  {get;set;}
    public ModelName2 ModelName2  {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly but my next problem is still there where I can't populate DropDownList from GenderDD model.

Comment: I think it would help us if you posted the code for your view

Answer (score 2):

Use viewbag to pass data as below,
You can write in controller

```
var genderlist = new List<SelectListItem>
{
  new SelectListItem { code = "M", name = "Male" },
  new SelectListItem { code = "F", name = "Female" }                
};
viewbag.genderlist=genderlist;
```

You can write in view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.gender, new SelectList(ViewBag.genderlist, "code", "name"))
```